# GTK Widgets needed to implement auto-completion for Gtk TextView

Tags: gtk, gnome, vala

I am a novice at using GTK widgets. I want to show a autocompletion drop-down when user types something in GTK-TextView. User should be able to select the preferred item from the drop-down Menu using keyboard or mouse. In case of GTK-TextEntry, we have built-in support for autocompletion. I want something similar for GTK TextView. Example code would be really helpful.. thanks..

[image: Example image]

Comment: Is [Gtk.SourceView](http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=gtksourceview-3.0/Gtk.SourceView) with connected [Gtk.SourceCompletion](http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=gtksourceview-3.0/Gtk.SourceCompletion) (gtksourceview-3.0) an acceptable alternative?